# What is wrong with this recursive method? (java)

Tags: java

The method is for a calculator and is supposed to return log2(n). All of the methods used (monus which is minus spelled wrong) power, ect) are written correctly. s(n) just adds one to n and p(n) subtracts one.

when I call the method in the main it gets the remainder right, but always returns 0 for the answer. this confuses me. I am sure it has to do with the fact that i am reinitializing answer to 0 each time the method is called but shouldn't that not matter because it is always going to get set to x before it returns anything?

x is a private static variable that has been set to 0 outside of the method.

```
public static long v(long n)
{
    long answer =0;

    if (power(2,x) > n)
    {
        x = p(x);
        setRemainder(monus(n,power(2,x)));
        answer = x;
    }
    else if(power(2,x) ==n)
    {   
        setRemainder(0);
        answer = x;
    }
    else
    {
        x = s(x);
        v(n);
    }
    x=0;// reset x so it can be used again.  
    return answer;

}
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: You recurse in by calling `v(n)`, but you never do anything with what you find.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the line:

```
v(n);
```

to:

```
answer = v(n);
```

Right now, if the last else block is executed, the answer variable is not changed - so it's still 0.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was originally just returning x directly, but then i realized I needed to re use it for some other methods, so I reset it to 0 and added in  the answer variable, but I completely over looked that.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you make the recursive call in the `else` statement but don't assign this to anything when the recursive call returns.

Consider this:

On your first call: `x = 0` so probably going to the else statement and enter the recursion. At some point of recursion one of your conditional statements will be true and in this case `answer` is returned but not assigned in the way back down the stack of recursive calls.

So would look like this:

```
  1: v(n)   // this calls v(n) again
    2: v(n) returns answer = x // this returns an answer
  1: returns answer = 0  //  now the return falls down a level to where the recursive 
                         //  call was and the answer is lost as was not assigned
```